# If $\lim_{x \to\infty} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x \to\infty} x f'(x) = 0$, then is $\lim_{x \to\infty} f(x) = 0?$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $f(x)$ is increasing in $x.$ If $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to\infty} f(x)$ exists and  $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to\infty} x f'(x) = 0$, then is  $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to\infty} f(x) = 0?$

I think that it is true because $f'(x)$ decreases faster than $\dfrac{1}{x}$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: **HINT**: If you add a constant to $f(x)$, does that change $f'(x)$?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is increasing in $x$ then $f'(x) \geq 0$. The fact that $\lim_{x \to\infty} x f'(x)=0$ would imply that $f'(x)$ would be zero somewhere. The derivative of a constant is zero.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer is no. An example is $f(x) = c - \frac{1}{x}$ for any constant c.